# Mixamo walking animations, how do I stop them from resetting position?

Tags: animation, blend-files

I am adding some animations from Mixamo to my Blender project and am struggling to create a constant walk.

To keep it simple, I have combined two animations in the NLA, idle which then moves in to walk.

I am aware I could use the "In Place" option on Mixamo and position the animation myself, however, I feel the walking looks too unnatural.

I have used the automatic walking forward which looks much better but at the end of each animation cycle, it restarts back to the place it started.

Is there a way I can have the animation just keep walking until a certain keyframe where I can add another animation?

I've been pulling my hair out on this for days and can't seem to find an answer.

Edit: Added Blend file [image]

Comment: Could you add a blend file showing our problem to your question?  ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: Done! I've removed the bodies as it was going to push the 30MB size limit on the Blender upload site.

Comment: shouldn't need the bodies.  I will look at the file when I get a chance. Hopefully someone else will find our problem sooner than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to NLA and temporarily uncheck the Armature button, so that NLA doesn't affect the rig.

Open the Injury walk animation into an action editor, disable the blue arrow (only show selected) and enable the quad button (Show hidden), then delete the last frame (frame 50).

Select all keyframes, press shift D, 49, Enter.
Select all keyframes, press Shift D, 98, Enter.
Repeat as much as needed.

[image]

Select the main root bone (the hip in this case), open a graph editor, select its Z location channel and press Shift H to isolate its view.

Go to frame 50, hold Ctrl and click on the right side of the cursor to select every keyframe above 50, then press G, Y, adjust the curve and confirm with Left mouse button.

Repeat for the others ramps.

[image]

Now you can combine this new action (which lasts 196 frames, 4 walk cycles) in the NLA editor (you will have to delete and then re-import the injury action in the NLA, for refreshing the editor's data).

Comment: Thank you so much! It's a bit fiddly but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you again!