How to location offset a set of keyframes?
I have an automatically generated walk cycle on my character from mixamo keyframed out 
But if I try to copy keyframes to extend the walk he just jumps back to starting location and repeats the same walk cycle in same position. How do I make the character keep walking? How do I offset all the keyframe locations by the distance he walked so the walk cycle doesn't restart his position?

Have you looked at the graph editor, to see the values of these keyframes? It may become obvious once you copy/paste which values need to continue increasing.

Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/243333/mixamo-walking-animations-how-do-i-stop-them-from-resetting-position/243362#243362
